# How to check if a Select web element contains certain text using js and selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I a hidden dropdown web element that currently im un-hidding and selecting by value like this:

```
val js: JavascriptExecutor = driver.asInstanceOf[JavascriptExecutor]
js.executeScript("$('.select-upload_company_id>.center').html(" + someInt + ")") //visible one
js.executeScript("$('#company_id option[value=\"" + someInt + "\"]').eq(1).attr('selected','selected')")
```

Now, this works perfectly, but now I want to select the element by visible text...

So I tried to do something like:

```
val js: JavascriptExecutor = driver.asInstanceOf[JavascriptExecutor]
js.executeScript("$('.select-upload_company_id>.center').html(" + "Test" + ")") //visible one
js.executeScript("$('#company_id option[contains=\"" + "Test" + "\"]').eq(1).attr('selected','selected')")
```

but its not working...does someone either know why it dosent work or have a bettes and simpler solution? I'm programming in scala but java solutions will be fine too.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `contains` selector should be written like `#company_id option:contains("Test")`

So:

`$('#company_id option:contains("Test")').eq(1)...`

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGqXzG

Comment: That's in your example code... It selects the 2nd occurrence of the matching DOM element. So, if there are 3 options that have the word "Test" in them, .eq(1) would match the second .eq(0) would be the first.

Comment: I did this: js.executeScript("$('.select-upload_company_id>.center').html('Test')") //visible one
js.executeScript("$('#company_id option:contains(\"Test\")').eq(1).attr('selected','selected')")

Comment: it works, but its only showing my the text that it selected, but its not really selected